# read word file with text and picture

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, ms-word

i have a word(Office) file. this file content text and picture.

how can read this file and show in `<textarea> </textarea>`;

Comment: Are you wanting just the text or both the text and image?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to display rich content like word document on UI is through html. You can `export your word document to HTML and render it to asp.net UI controls`. If you prefer, textarea, you have to implement custom textarea to support images from word-html file.

Also, you can use [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to display this word-html file instead of textarea.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can read this into a `<textarea>` as you ask. *(I will watch to see if somebody else shows how, because I want to see that too...)* I believe the closest result you will get is to open the document into an `<iframe>` with the `application/msword` content type. If you are looking for some flexiblity in this, wrap the space in a `<div>` and swap out `<textarea> for <iframe>` at the server when appropriate.